# information send to microsoft by joining to microsoft improvement program group

Tags: windows-server-2008, wsus, windows-update

I wanna deploy a WSUS server 2008r2 in my network .during deployment I saw an option "**Join to Microsoft improvement program group**" .
I'm curious that what kinds of information will send to Microsoft after joining to this group.
I know this group is created to improve Microsoft product ,But I wanna know what information will send exactly?

Answer (score 2):

From the related [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618322.aspx) article:

> **Specific information sent**: The information that is sent includes
>   details about the computer hardware configuration (such as the number
>   of processors and screen resolution), performance and reliability
>   (such as how quickly a program responds when you click a button), and
>   information about use of the system (such as how many folders a user
>   typically creates on the desktop). It also includes information about
>   the use of features such as Event Viewer and Remote Assistance. For
>   additional details, see the link to the privacy statement later in
>   this list.

Comment: Doesn't it send any information about my network ?like number of clients or range of Ip addresses ?

Comment: The linked article contains the official statement from Microsoft about what data they send. If you want to know more, ask them (but don't expect an answer) and if you don't trust them, disable this stuff.